# Game Center integration delay

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center

From what I understand:

- GameCenter integration requires the app to be registered on iTunes Connect
- Once the app is registered, a binary must be published within 3 months (otherwise I cannot reuse this app name)

Shall I assume that integration of GameCenter features in my app must be developed in less than 3 months?

Is there any way to have more time for this development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe register a placeholder app which you use for development and adding Game Center then when you're nearer competition create the actual app within iTunes Connect and re-create the Game Center set up. This would give you more time and keep your applications name free for use.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give a try. It just looks like such an obvious issue, I was just wondering what is the usual workflow for GameCenter integration.

Answer (score 1):

I registered a dummy name (real name plus a zero) because I was sure I wouldn't be ready to submit the app within three months. It turned out that I was given 6 months. After 5 months I got this email:

/"
You have not yet uploaded a binary for your app, xxx0. Our records show that this app was created in iTunes Connect more than 150 days ago.

If you do not upload a binary for your app by 06 September 2012 (Pacific Time), it will be deleted from iTunes Connect. The app name will then be available for another developer to use.
"/

It's good that I submitted a dummy name because the app won't be ready within 6 months either. Now I've submitted the real name so I won't care when the dummy name expires. But be aware that there is no way to copy the information from one app over to another. You have to go through the whole tedious time-consuming process of entering the information about your app over again, and the game center info, and the in-app purchase info if you have in-app purchase. Then you have to figure out how to change the name of your app in Xcode. It's all doable but annoying of Apple to enforce that time limit on amateur/hobby developers.